# C++ HTTP client hangs on read() call after GET request

Tags: c++, linux, http, request, freeze

```
std::string HTTPrequest = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.yahoo.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

write(socket, HTTPrequest.c_str(), sizeof(HTTPrequest));

char pageReceived[4096];

int bytesReceived = read(socket, pageReceived, 4096);
```

I've got an HTTP client program that I run from my terminal. I've also got a webserver program. Using the webserver as a test, I can verify that the socket creation and attachment works correctly.

I create the request as shown above, then write to the socket. Using print statements, I can see that the code moves beyond the write call. However, it hangs on the read call.

I can't figure out what's going on - my formatting looks correct on the request.

Any ideas? Everything seems to work perfectly fine when I connect to my webserver, but both www.yahoo.com and www.google.com cause a hang. I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, `sizeof` gives you the number of bytes required to hold a type, regardless of its contents. So you are not sending the full request, only `sizeof(std::string)` bytes. You want `HTTPRequest.size()` (which gives you the number of bytes the *value* stored in `HTTPRequest` takes), not `sizeof(HTTPrequest)` (which gives you the number of bytes a `std::string` itself requires).

Comment: Totally correct and fixed my problem. Thank you! I'm wondering - why did it work when contacting my webserver but not when contacting a "real" site?

Comment: @TylerM. Perhaps `sizeof(std::string)` was large enough to cover the entire request or perhaps your webserver didn't wait for the entire request.